Disable webview full screen in Android - Flutter - Inappwebview
I am trying to disable the fullscreen mode when the user presses the full screen button in the webview content.
I tried by setting this property isElementFullscreenEnabled to false and it works perfectly on iOS. But, I am unable to find a equivalent solution for achieving the same in Android also. Any help is appreciated.
Edit:
Executing this fixed the issue
await controller.evaluateJavascript(source:
'Element.prototype.requestFullscreen = function() {};',
);

